# Filter based on matching condition in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm trying to execute a command to only keep rows where the 'ID' is the same in column Y as it is in column X. In other words, keep the row if the 'ID' in column Y matches the ID in column X.

edit: here's the code that is close but not quite there. What I need is to add a condition to the Y column. So it should keep rows where the ID in column X equals the ID in column Y **when column Y = '34'**.

```
data %>%
  filter(ID %in% X == ID %in% Y)
```

Comment: Check out the ‘join’ functions. If you need more detailed help check out in the help section how to ask a good question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Do you mean `df %>% filter(x == y)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join or just do something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:13, y = c(1:5,7:14))
    x  y
1   1  1
2   2  2
3   3  3
4   4  4
5   5  5
6   6  7
7   7  8
8   8  9
9   9 10
10 10 11
11 11 12
12 12 13
13 13 14

rows_to_select <- which(df$x==df$y,TRUE)

df[rows_to_select,]
  x y
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'which' function in base R.  Example:

```
set.seed(7) # create toy dataframe
x1 <- sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
x2 <- sample(1:2, 10, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(x1, x2)
df
   x1 x2
1   2  2
2   2  1
3   2  1
4   1  1
5   2  1
6   2  2
7   1  2
8   1  1
9   1  1
10  1  2

keep <- which(df$x1 == df$x2) # only this line
keep
1 4 6 8 9

df2 <- df[keep , ] # and this line required for the reduced dataframe
df2
  x1 x2
1  2  2
4  1  1
6  2  2
8  1  1
9  1  1
```